# Drupal 8 - Installation blank page

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am trying to install Drupal 8 (so far tried 8.0.3 and 8.0.1) but I am unable to get past first setup step.

When I choose language, I got empty blank page without any error or clue.

I checked around to find that it might be related to PHP version, but Drupal requirements (as seen on drupal.org) are PHP 5.5.9 and higher. My current PHP version is 5.6.17, which seems to be correct according to official requirements.

Platform OS X

```
PHP 5.6.17 (homebrew)
Server version: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix)
mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503
```

Any clue?

**Update**
Is there any way how to see what's going on during installation? Does Drupal create some logfile? I've read dozens of articles how to see logs within DB table, but since Drupal is not installed yet then I don't have any other way how to monitor what's wrong.

Comment: Have you tried checking write permissions on sites/default directory?

Comment: Used sudo chmod -R 777 ./drupal and nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see what's happening on the Web server during drupal installation, you need to set your apache log level configuration to **debug**  and tail your apache log files within a terminal with

```
tail -f /path/to/your/apache/log/files/*
```

This way you will learn able to folllw both access and error files